# In Android S, Can a system app (actually a service) perform uninstall of APKs silently without being a device owner?

Tags: android, kotlin, system, uninstallation, silent

I am writing a system app (a service) and its job is to monitor android app installs (on Android 12) and if required uninstall it silently. I was able to setup a Broadcast receiver for "Intent.ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED" and this works - I get notified on any app install.

However when I try to uninstall the application I am not able to. I have been searching this and other places for a week and have tried several options like below

1. Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su -c 'pm uninstall " + packageName + "'"); [Needs rooting]
2. uninstallIntent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_UNINSTALL_PACKAGE, packageURI) [Activies are not allowed from background service - even it were allowed it would have not been silent]
3. PackageInstaller.uninstall(appPackage, sender.intentSender) [Runs but no action is taken - probably because it requires device owner or profile owner]

So, before proceeding with more such trials, I am trying to check with the broader community if there is even a possibility of a solution for a System Service to silently uninstall an APK that it has not installed. Appreciate your time/effort in answering this. Thanks

Comment: I know that your app need to be either a Device owner or have Device Administrators access to Install an apk. Uninstall part i am not sure. With device owner it should work, because that's what MDMs are using. If it works with Device Administrator mode, it would be easier.

Comment: Thanks Ajith. Unfortunately my requirement is to remain just a system app and not a device owner and still perform the uninstall. I am trying to check if that is possible.

Comment: I am not sure how to do that. But remember that to be a System app, you need to Partner with the phone OEM and have your app signed with the same signature of the OS. And you will need to do this with each of the OEMs your phone supports.

Comment: Correct. I have already done that - made my app a System app. But even after being a system app it is still not able to silently uninstall other apps. That is where I am stuck now and trying to check.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I thought it was pretty clear. I want to be able to uninstall other apps/packages silently from within my app programmatically. My app being a system app running as a service.